# Support SAML SSO and normal login

Tags: spring, single-sign-on, saml

I have an application which is accessed by two types of users, internal and external. 
I need to authenticate external users using SAML.
I need to authenticate internal users with the normal form-based login. My application need to support both types of users. I use spring security frame work.

Is it possible to support both types of users? if so can you suggest the approach at high level?   Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to support both simultaneously. I believe it's covered thoroughly in the docs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It would be of great help if you could please suggest specific URLs/link that cover this.

Comment: As long as the user has not authenticated, how should the application know if the user is internal or external?

IMHO this can only be achieved if you deploy the same application twice or different URIs with different filter chains

Comment: I plan to use /ext/ as part of URI for identifying external users who call only a small subset of services exposed by my application. URIs with /ext/ in them should go through SAML authentication.  All other URLs are treated as normal internal users and taken through form-based login

Answer (score 4):

You can easily enable support for both form and SAML authentication with configuration similar to this:

```
<http entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <form-login login-page="/login" />
    <custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
    <custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
</http>
```

Make sure that your AuthenticationManager contains the samlAuthenticationProvider. And of course include other configuration parts from the Spring SAML sample application.

You can then create your custom login page which presents user with username+password fields for form-based authentication and a link/picture (or multiple of them) which initialize authentication with the IDP (by redirecting user to scheme://host:port/saml/login?idp=selectedIdpEntityId).

Your users then decide which one to use - depending on whether they's internal or external.

The part of Spring SAML documentation touching on this subject is in chapter [Spring Security integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-integration-spring-security).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The application has to transparently handle the users' authentication. 
External users are handled via SAML authentication (by looking at the URI for example with /myapp/ext/service1). 

If the URI is /myapp/service1, user is presented with normal login screen if a valid session does not already exist.

Comment: In that case implement a custom AuthenticationEntryPoint which determines the type of user and either redirects to the form login page, or starts SAML authentication. Your implementation will be referred from the "entry-point-ref" attribute.

Comment: Just to add to Vladimir's answer - there is a spring-security class called 'DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint' which is useful for selecting different authenticationEntryPoints based on RequestMatchers